# use of rand function to assign a value randomly

Tags: c

i am doing a homework. i put rand function in a loop.

```
int counter = 1;

while ( counter <= 10 ){
   variable1 = rand() % 5 + 1;
   printf("%d", variable);
   counter = counter + 1;
```

In this code, rand function assigns different value to variable called variable1 but sometimes it assigns same value because range of rand function is narrow. how can i perform that rand function assign different number to variable at the time when loop returns every time.

Comment: To get better randomness, use `RtlGenRandom` or `CryptGenRandom`.

Comment: .. so your question is "how to avoid the same number being returned consecutively from the random function"?

Comment: Given a good (even "the best", whatever that might mean) random number generator that only returns numbers between 1 and 5, you will always have a 20% chance that the next random number generated will be the same one you just got. If you have an RNG that never produces the same number twice in a row, it's not a very good one...

Comment: It's quite impossible to generate 10 random numbers in the range 1..5 with no repetitions. Do you mean that  you don't want the same number twice in a row? Then you need to choose one of 5 numbers the first time, then one of 4 numbers (eliminating the one you just got) on successive iterations.

Comment: Although on a closer look you're generating 10 numbers, but your range is 1-5. What exactly do you want? Globally unique numbers are obviously impossible unless you get only 5 numbers or you increase the range to 1-10. Do you want that there are no repeated pairs, e.g. `{...,3, 3,...}` is wrong but `{..., 3, 1, 3,...}` is OK?

Answer (score 1):

While `rand()` is not the greatest random function it should do the trick for many jobs and certainly for most homework.   It is perfectly valid to have the same number returned twice in a row from a random function -- as the function should not have any memory of what values were previously returned.

The best way to understand this, is with an example of a coin-toss.  Every coin toss is random, and the coin has no memory of the previous toss, so it is possible to flip a coin 32 times in a row and they all comes up `head` -- if every coin toss is a bit in a 32 bit integer you have created the binary value of integer zero.

However human tend to think (intuition) that having the same value returned more than once is "wrong" for a random function -- but our intuition is wrong on this account.

If you for some reason **do** want to not repeat the number from one loop to the next, then you will need to program that regardless of which random functions you use -- since **any** random function would be capable of returning the same values twice.

So something like this would do it;

```
int counter = 1;
int prevValue = -1;

while ( counter <= 10 ){
   do {
      variable1 = rand();
   } while (variable1 == prevValue);
   prevValue = variable1;

   variable1 = variable1 % 5 + 1;
   printf("%d", variable);
   counter = counter + 1;
}
```

Note that this is still capable of printing the same value twice, since 10 and 15 would be different values before the `%5` but would be the same after.  If you want the `%5` to be taken into account, so the `printf` never print the same value twice in a row, you would need to move the %5 inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet i can't find which instruction is the last one inside while. If you want to get different numbers every program run you should use srand() function before while.

But as you mentioned before. Your range (1 - 5) is to narrow to get 10 unique values every time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  int counter = 1;
  int variable1 = 0;


  srand(time(NULL));

  while ( counter <= 10 ) {
    variable1 = rand() % 5 + 1;
    printf("%d ", variable1);
    counter = counter + 1;
  }
  putchar('\n');

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate a *unique* list of random numbers, you must check each number generated against the list of numbers previously generated to insure there is no duplicate. The easiest way is to store your previously generated numbers in an array to check against. Then you simply iterate over the values in the array, and if your most recent number is already there, create a new one.

For example, you can use a simple flag to check if your are `done`. e.g.

```
    while (counter < MAXI){
        int done = 0;
        while (!done) {           /* while done remains 0 (not done) */
            done = 1;
            tmp = rand() % MAXI + 1;        /* generate radom number */
            for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)   /* check again previous  */
                if (tmp == array[i])        /* if num already exists */
                    done = 0;               /* set as (not done)     */
        }
        array[counter++] = tmp;             /* assign random value   */
    }
```

Or you can use the old faithful `goto` to do the same thing:

```
    while (counter < MAXI) {
      gennum:  
        tmp = rand() % MAXI + 1;
        for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
            if (tmp == array[i])
                goto gennum;
        array[counter++] = tmp;
    }
```

Whichever makes more sense to you. Putting together a full example, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for rand */
#include <time.h>   /* for time */

enum { MAXI = 10 };

int main (void) {

    int array[MAXI] = {0}, counter = 0, i, tmp;

    srand (time (NULL));    /* initialize the semi-random number generator */

    while (counter < MAXI){
        int done = 0;
        while (!done) {           /* while done remains 0 (not done) */
            done = 1;
            tmp = rand() % MAXI + 1;        /* generate radom number */
            for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)   /* check again previous  */
                if (tmp == array[i])        /* if num already exists */
                    done = 0;               /* set as (not done)     */
        }
        array[counter++] = tmp;             /* assign random value   */
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAXI; i++)
        printf (" array[%2d] = %d\n", i, array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

(*note:* the number your `mod` (`%`) the generated number by must be equal to or greater than the number of values you intend to collect -- otherwise, you cannot generate a unique list.)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/randarray
 array[ 0] = 8
 array[ 1] = 2
 array[ 2] = 7
 array[ 3] = 9
 array[ 4] = 1
 array[ 5] = 4
 array[ 6] = 3
 array[ 7] = 10
 array[ 8] = 6
 array[ 9] = 5
```

---

**A Shuffled Sequence**

Given the discussion in the comments, a good point was raised concerning whether your goal was to create unique set of random numbers (above) or a random set from a sequence of numbers (e.g. any sequence, say `1-50` in shuffled order). In the event you are looking for the latter, then an efficient method to create the shuffled-sequence is using a modified Fisher-Yates shuffle knows as [**The "inside-out" algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_.22inside-out.22_algorithm).

The algorithm allows populating an *uninitialized* array with a shuffled sequence from any source of numbers (whether the source can be any manner of generating numbers). Essentially, the function will swap the values within an array at the current index with the value held at a randomly generated index. An implementation would look like:

```
/** fill an uninitialized array using inside-out fill */
void insideout_fill (int *a, int n)
{
    int i, val;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        val = i ? randhq (i) : 0;
        if (val != i)
            a[i] = a[val];
        a[val] = i;         /* i here can be any source, function, etc.. */
    }
}
```

(where `randhq` is any function that generates a random value `(0 <= val < n)`)

A short example program that uses the function above to generate a shuffled array of value from `0 - (n-1)` is shown below. The example generates a shuffled sequence of values in `array` using the inside-out algorithm, and then confirms the sequence generation by sorting the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void insideout_fill (int *a, int n);
int randhq (int max);
void prnarray (int *a, size_t n, size_t strd, int wdth);
int intcmp (const void *a, const void *b);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    srand (time (NULL));
    int arrsz = argc > 1 ? (int)strtol (argv[1], NULL, 10) : 50;
    int array[arrsz];

    insideout_fill (array, arrsz);
    printf ("\n array initialized with inside-out fill:\n\n");
    prnarray (array, arrsz, 10, 4);

    qsort (array, arrsz, sizeof *array, intcmp);
    printf ("\n value confirmation for inside-out fill:\n\n");
    prnarray (array, arrsz, 10, 4);

    return 0;
}

/** fill an uninitialized array using inside-out fill */
void insideout_fill (int *a, int n)
{
    int i, val;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        val = i ? randhq (i) : 0;
        if (val != i)
            a[i] = a[val];
        a[val] = i;      /* i here can be any source, function, etc.. */
    }
}

/** high-quality random value in (0 <= val <= max) */
int randhq (int max)
{
    unsigned int
        /* max <= RAND_MAX < UINT_MAX, so this is okay. */
        num_bins = (unsigned int) max + 1,
        num_rand = (unsigned int) RAND_MAX + 1,
        bin_size = num_rand / num_bins,
        defect   = num_rand % num_bins;

    int x;
    /* carefully written not to overflow */
    while (num_rand - defect <= (unsigned int)(x = rand()));

    /* truncated division is intentional */
    return x/bin_size;
}

/** print array of size 'n' with stride 'strd' and field-width 'wdth' */
void prnarray (int *a, size_t n, size_t strd, int wdth)
{
    if (!a) return;
    register size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf (" %*d", wdth, a[i]);
        if (!((i + 1) % strd)) putchar ('\n');
    }
}

/** qsort integer compare */
int intcmp (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return *((int *)a) - *((int *)b);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_io_fill

 array initialized with inside-out fill:

   40   15   35   17   27   28   20   14   32   39
   31   25   29   45    4   16   13    9   49    7
   11   23    8   33   48   37   41   34   19   38
   24   26   47   44    5    0    6   21   43   10
    2    1   18   22   46   30   12   42    3   36

 value confirmation for inside-out fill:

    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29
   30   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39
   40   41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48   49
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Once you keep an array of previous results you realize that what you're really doing is creating a random permutation of an array of numbers, what [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) does in C++. Such a permutation should have a cost that doesn't depend on the likelihood of repetitions in the output of the random generator: you should be calling `rand()` exactly N*m times, where N is the length of the array, and m is a constant integer, usually 1.

Comment: I agree with the premise, it's a lot easier to fill an array with `1 - 10` and shuffle, but that's not the approach the person has taken. If the OP wants to go that route that's fine, but the OP asked about an approach with `rand`. If you want to re-write his question for him, post another answer.

Comment: I'm not saying "don't use rand()", I'm merely saying that you call it more than N times for no good reason. Your implementation looks to be O(N^2): call it for ever larger N and see how many times `rand()` is called.  Since you already have the array, you can implement a Fisher-Yates shuffle on it and you'll be calling `rand()` only once per element, or at least O(N). This question and the answer are duplicates anyway.

Comment: No, I got it. The issues we are tossing about is only due to the sequential nature of the numbers from `1-10` (or `1-5` in original). If the random numbers being generated were `% 100 + 1`, then the same checks against duplication would be required, but the likelihood of an actual hit would be greatly reduced. However, a shuffle solution under those circumstances would not meet the random approach.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, as N grows the cost tends to 1 per element, so it is O(N). Can't do my series expansions today.

Comment: You were right as well for the sequential case. Your comments sent me down the Fisher-Yates rabbit hole which led to the [The "inside-out" algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_.22inside-out.22_algorithm), which if the OP was solely interested in creating a shuffled set of unique number is exactly what he would need. Given an uninitialized array, the algorithm populates the array in Fisher-Yates shuffled order. Which from an efficiency standpoint is exactly your original point with a single call to `rand` per element.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i perform that rand function assign different number to variable at the time when loop returns every time?

I take this to mean OP does not want to generate the same number twice in a row.

On subsequent iterations, use `%(n-1)`

```
int main(void) {
  int counter;
  int variable;
  for (counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++) {
    // First time in loop
    if (counter <= 1) {
      variable = rand() % 5 + 1;

    } else {
      int previous = variable;
      variable = rand() % (5 - 1) + 1;
      if (variable >= previous) variable++;
    }

    printf("%d\n", variable);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @David C. Rankin 1) Guaranteed to not repeat the previous value.  (tested 100,000,000 iterations) 2) `previous` is not used until the second iteration.  It is assigned on the first iteration.

Comment: @David C. Rankin Re-coded for testing/clarity.